# How to work notification when receive message

Tags: java, android, notifications, sms

I 'm working application to receive message but i want to appear notification when receive message

please, how is work  it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Player.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
notification = new Notification();
notification.tickerText = "App Name";
notification.icon = R.drawable.icon;
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
try {
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "App Name", "AppName~ ", pi);
} catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
}
startForeground(01, notification);
```

Comment: Add this code , in the onRecieve() of your Message. , And here you go what you need

Comment: in this line we are creating a live instance/ object of notification